# Receiving "Unauthorized" response trying to delete a document in a Cosmos DB collection using REST API

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I'm attempting to use the Cosmos DB REST API to delete a document from a collection.  However I continually receive the following error message:

> {"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can't serve the request. The wrong key is being used or the expected payload is not built as per the protocol. etc... etc...

I happen to be using PowerShell to call the REST API but I think this is incidental.  I've compared the call I'm making to the API reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/) and can't see any issues with it.

I'm passing a Read/Write key and am using nearly identical code (and the same Read/Write key) to successfully create a document, so I don't understand why DELETE doesn't work. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
    $sVerb = "DELETE"
    $sDateTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")
    $sAuthHeader = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -verb $sVerb -resourceLink $sResourceLink -resourceType $sResourceType -key $Key -keyType "master" -tokenVersion "1.0" -dateTime $sDateTime
    $sHeader = @{ "authorization"=$sAuthHeader;"x-ms-date"=$sDateTime;"x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey"="[ ""$PartitionKey"" ]";"x-ms-version"="2018-12-31" }
    $sContentType= "application/json"
    $sUri = "$sDBEndpoint$sResourceLink/docs/$DocId"

    $sResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $sVerb -ContentType $sContentType -Uri $sUri -Headers $sHeader -StatusCodeVariable "sReturnCode"
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You link is from early 2022.  Azure has moved to OATH2 credentials which will work with windows, linux, and MAC.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-10.2.0

Comment: Please share your complete code. Include the values of all variables like `$sResourceLink`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the steps which I tried to delete a document in a Cosmos DB collection using REST API:**

- `Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature` function generates an authorization signature for the Cosmos DB REST API.
- It creates an instance of the **HMACSHA256** cryptographic algorithm and sets the key to the decoded base64 $key.
- Constructs a `$payLoad` string containing various pieces of information in a specific format.
- Converts the hash to a base64-encoded string to create the `$signature`.
- `Delete-CosmosDbDocument` function uses `Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature` function to delete a document from a Cosmos DB collection.
- Establishes variables like $Verb, $ResourceType, and $DocumentID to builds the $ResourceLink.
- `header` constructs the headers for the HTTP request, including the authorization header, partition key, date, and Cosmos DB version.
- `queryUri` constructs the full URL for the DELETE request using the `$EndPoint` and `$ResourceLink`.
- `Delete-CosmosDbDocument` sends a DELETE request to the specified URL using `Invoke-RestMethod`.

**Code I tried with:**

```
Function Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$verb,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceLink,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$dateTime,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$keyType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$tokenVersion
    )

    $hmacSha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacSha256.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)

    $payLoad = "$($verb.ToLowerInvariant())`n$($resourceType.ToLowerInvariant())`n$resourceLink`n$($dateTime.ToLowerInvariant())`n`n"
    $hashPayLoad = $hmacSha256.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payLoad))
    $signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hashPayLoad);

    [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$keyType&ver=$tokenVersion&sig=$signature")
}

Function Delete-CosmosDbDocument
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$EndPoint,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$DataBaseId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$CollectionId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$MasterKey
    )

    $Verb = "DELETE"
    $ResourceType = "docs"
    $DocumentID = "4"
    $ResourceLink = "dbs/$DatabaseId/colls/$CollectionId/docs/$DocumentID"
    $KeyValue = "4"
    $partitionkey = "[""$($KeyValue)""]"

    $dateTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")
    $authHeader = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -verb $Verb -resourceLink $ResourceLink -resourceType $ResourceType -key $MasterKey -keyType "master" -tokenVersion "1.0" -dateTime $dateTime
    $header = @{authorization=$authHeader;"x-ms-version"="2018-12-31";"x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey"=$partitionkey;"x-ms-date"=$dateTime}
    $queryUri = "$EndPoint/$ResourceLink"  # Corrected line

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -Uri $queryUri -Headers $header -Verbose
    return $result.statuscode
}

$CosmosDBEndPoint = "*****" 
$DatabaseId = "testDb"                                  
$CollectionId = "testCont"                            
$MasterKey = "*****"                              

Delete-CosmosDbDocument -EndPoint $CosmosDBEndPoint -DataBaseId $DatabaseId -CollectionId $CollectionId -MasterKey $MasterKey -Verbose
```

**Input:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]